# How do I scrape an aspx website that seems to be generated using javascript and cannot be directly opened

Tags: javascript, java, python, html, asp.net

I Found that you cannot directly open the link that I am ultimately trying to scrape: https://publicindex.sccourts.org/Abbeville/PublicIndex/PISearch.aspx. But you can directly open the link right before: https://publicindex.sccourts.org/abbeville/publicindex/.
My issue is that I am trying to eventually navigate to the first link in a web scraper in python. But even when trying to open the 2nd link that I tested and verified on a regular browser like Chrome, the html that comes out is not the same as the html that the page has on the View Page Source when browsing to it in Chrome. This issue happened again and again using, urllib, BeautifulSoup, requests, RoboBrowser, and requests_html with html.render. So I tried using Selenium because I read that this would be needed if the page requires javascript enabled. But when I open https://publicindex.sccourts.org/abbeville/publicindex/ in selenium, before I can click on accept the browser redirects to the base website (https://www.sccourts.org/caseSearch/). I saw some other people scraping website that have aspx variables like __VIEWSTATE which this website does, but I am not sure what approach to take with this particular site. I prefer python but if there is an easier solution in java or some other language I am open to it! So what approach should I take for this site? This is the html of the https://publicindex.sccourts.org/abbeville/publicindex/ site:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>
    Public Index Search
</title>
    <!-- Set the viewport width to device width for mobile -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" /><link href="../SCJDCommonWebFiles/SCJDStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link rel="shortcut icon" href="../SCJDCommonWebFiles/Images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" /><link rel="icon" href="../SCJDCommonWebFiles/Images/favicon.ico" type="image/ico" />
</head>
<body id="MainPage">
    <form method="post" action="./" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="ContentPlaceHolder1_ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTE0MjkzMTY0NDZkZO9AfFymJFs2oYtw0NdvHHX24ken" />
</div>

<script nonce="44zvId2606ALq6COtXWax194">(function(a){var d=document;if(d.readyState==="complete")return;var w=window;var s=d.currentScript;addEventListener("QDDFxBgUl",function f(e){e.stopImmediatePropagation();removeEventListener("QDDFxBgUl",f);e.detail.init("A_SftyZ2AQAAj-rSLifZN8fPTkYzU3JXZNntKqDT7TyHx8CUbCjSP1gGAxv6ASO_Cfaucr5iwH8AAOfvAAAAAA==","csmObzTJRl8Pi6U30n1f9=dIx47rhMuWotjZV2gpkB5SvDQwyGNYaHFq-LCK_AeEX",[],[537446516,1519189668,1031653497,413076837,861185844,1429182448,1631016849,396020441],"44zvId2606ALq6COtXWax194","44zvId2606ALq6COtXWax194",[[/(?:)/,/^((?=.*publicindex\.sccourts\.org$))/i,/^((?!\/$)(?!\/$))/i,/(?:)/],[[["GET"],[0,1,0,2,0]],[["POST"],[0,1,0,3,0]]]],a)},true);s&&s.parentNode.removeChild(s);d.write("<script "+('nonce="'+"44zvId2606ALq6COtXWax194"+'" ')+('src="'+"/b540ee9e345645bca774a11fc6c63a7a.js?seed=AMBGpiZ2AQAAwywUUZtzcNTN8yJXGAkN6cV3iln-3mGyunI6jxqxVqqUf0jR"+'" ')+('id="'+"593e2ee16e58f519a5d512bd17d93da9"+'"')+"></scr"+"ipt>")}(typeof arguments==="undefined"?void 0:arguments))</script><script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>


<script src="/Abbeville/PublicIndex/WebResource.axd?d=yHSk03n8qhGuYU3dqttnQ71qTt_0El3n1mxBXim4Y_-Y3mTP08Bvg1wOhE6CNGMfa0pKDFyPqFYCSLv2UBjX7AKLbHI1&amp;t=636776545224055265" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script src="/Abbeville/PublicIndex/ScriptResource.axd?d=Mkw4QIfUysnyQFhWpSU3cpRAOR84s719g9N0uJb6WluyvHTwL48NXPe4rwN0cPC7Gr6I9pZZph6TlEkVqfYsPXI7ZHd1OJzbro9C70-Bx13mFOPo0&amp;t=27117261" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Abbeville/PublicIndex/ScriptResource.axd?d=d8-wk7BomsPtH4YvLTJ1UzDNDQNd_YVgR7altkItLWhH5yOCDaUGJHcNTeOKDRiE1M_grO76wv2e-vwpgB-KU5rZQ7UxIpKqWPL9zNh13ZS_I0GMMssjEQcya90iKRQSiH2ymA2&amp;t=27117261" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="1B7E8EBE" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__PREVIOUSPAGE" id="__PREVIOUSPAGE" value="BsW216wqQxCtuIvrGWmJQq2SzKwzsohf-kqWPg_ixAZV5lsccN3qLaQAoEWdFDudUVNmZqLDHlVu_jjRlouMpBTtLyyx8OET2D0coFsN4lkn11MM0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEdAANnUhit7/TqA0EIrEA5S0S0kfXFdoRld1R/CA4tdNG91yIhI+6i/cUuX4RsMQK8Skk79cNANwPzNawq72wqYHHLPOBqiw==" />
</div>
        <div id="pagewrapper">
            <div id="pagecontent">
                <table class="pageHeading" enableviewstate="false">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left">
                            <img id="ImageLeft" class="headingImage" src="../SCJDCommonWebFiles/Images/HeaderLeft.jpg" alt="Left Heading Image" align="left" style="border-style:None;" />
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">
                            <span id="LabelHeadingCounty">Abbeville County</span>
                            <br />
                            <span id="LabelHeadingCircuit">Eighth Judicial Circuit</span>
                            <br />
                            <span id="LabelApplicationName">Public Index</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <img id="ImageRight" class="headingImage" src="../SCJDCommonWebFiles/Images/HeaderRight.jpg" alt="Right Heading Image" align="right" style="border-style:None;" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <hr class="horizontalSeparator" />
                <div id="linkBar" class="linksSection">
                    <a id="HyperLinkHome" href="http://www.abbevillecountysc.com">Abbeville County Home Page</a>
                    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<a href="http://www.sccourts.org/">South Carolina Judicial Department Home Page</a>
<a href="http://www.sc.gov/">SC.GOV Home Page</a>
                </div>
                <hr class="horizontalSeparator" />
                <div>
                    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function hidemodal() {
            $find('mpeBID').hide();
            return false;
        }

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ToolkitScriptManager1', 'form1', [], [], [], 90, 'ctl00');
//]]>
</script>

    <div id="disclaimsection" class="disclaimer">
        <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_LabelDisclaimer" class="disclaimerText"><br/>Neither the County nor any agency, officer, elected official or
employee of the County, warrants the accuracy, reliability or timeliness of any
information on this web site and shall not be liable for any losses caused by
such reliance on the accuracy, reliability or timeliness of such information,
including, but not limited to incidental and consequential damages. This
publication is provided &quot;as is&quot; without warranty of kind, either
expressed or implied, including, but not limited to, the implied warranties of
merchantability, fitness for a particular purpose or non-infringement. The
County maintains all immunities as provided in the South Carolina Tort Claims
Act.
<br/><br/>Portions of such information may be incorrect or not current. Any person or entity who
relies on any information obtained from this web site does so at his or her own
risk. In addition, nothing contained within this web site is an official record
of the County or the elected officials responsible therefore. All official
records of the County and the offices of countywide elected officials are on
file in their respective offices and may be reviewed by the public at those
offices.
<br/><br/>A person preparing or filing a document for recordation or filing in the official
records may not include a social security, driver's license, state
identification, passport, checking account, savings account, credit card, or
debit card number, or personal identification (PIN) code, or passwords in the
document, unless expressly required by law. An individual has a right to
request a register of deeds or clerk of court to remove, from an image or copy
of an official record placed on a publicly available Internet web site or on a
publicly available Internet web site used by a register of deeds or clerk of
court to display public records, any social security, driver's license, state
identification, passport, checking account, savings account, credit card, or
debit card number, or personal identification (PIN) code, or passwords
contained in an official record. The request must be made in writing and
delivered by mail, facsimile, or electronic transmission or in person, to the
register of deeds or clerk of court. The request must specify the
identification page number that contains the social security, driver's license,
state identification, passport, checking account, savings account, credit card,
debit card number, or personal identification (PIN) code, or passwords to be
redacted. There is no fee for the redaction pursuant to request.
<br/><br/><p>Access to the South Carolina Judicial Department Public Index web sites 
by a site data scraper or any similar software intended to discover and extract data from a website through automated, 
repetitive querying for the purpose of collecting such data is expressly prohibited.</p>
<br/>
<p style='text-align: center;font-weight: bold'>I have read and accept this disclaimer and responsibility for the use of this information:</p></span>
        <div id="ContentPlaceHolder1_PanelDiscButtons" class="centeredDiv" style="width:50%;">
    
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ButtonAccept" value="Accept" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ButtonAccept" title="Accept Disclaimer" class="actionButton" />
            <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ButtonDecline" value="Decline" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ButtonDecline&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, &quot;&quot;, &quot;http://www.abbevillecountysc.com&quot;, false, false))" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ButtonDecline" title="Decline Disclaimer" class="actionButton" />
            <br />
        
</div>
    </div>

                </div>
                <hr class="horizontalSeparator" />
                <div id="pagefooter" class="scjdcopyright">
                    <span id="Copyright">CMSWeb 6.1 © 2019 South Carolina Judicial Branch • All rights reserved </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, asp.net pages are not really run by scripting code that exists in the browser side.

the code you write to drive these pages is vb.net, or C#. You don't write markup, and it is server side code that runs and renders the page.

For example. If I have this aspx page markup?

[image]

In above, you can see the aspx markup. But you can also see the web forms designer. In fact, I can expand the forms designer, and simply drag + drop the controls onto the web form (you visual design the web page). So, I don't even really have to look at the markup.

Ok, so when I click on the button above? Well, just like say VB or Access that I dropped some buttons on the form? Well, you have what is called code behind, or server side code. It is not JavaScript.

So, here is what the code looks like for that button stub:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim rst As DataTable
    rst = MyRst("SELECT ID, HotelName, City FROM tblHotels ORDER BY HotelName")

    GridView1.DataSource = rst
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Now I did not write the sub/end sub. I just typed in some simple clean VB code.

(you can use c#, or vb.net).

Now, here is what you see on the web page when I click that button:

[image]

So, do  you see any JavaScript? (no!!!)

So the problem here is you have to say think of how you would screen scrape a desktop accounting program. You can say get some mouse click routine to click on a form button, but that's about ALL you can do.

How you going to setup the server side code and variables in a routine?

I mean, lets take the above grid view, and say drag in a button.

Now I have this:

[image]

And I dropped in that text box.

So, the select button code is now:

```
   Dim myGridrow As GridViewRow = GridView1.SelectedRow

   TextBox1.Text = GfIX(myGridrow, "HotelName")
```

So, if I click on a button, then the above two lines of easy VB code (or c#) runs.

And we get this;

[image]

So, it kind of important to realize that while I wrote ONLY a few lines of code - and server side code in a clean language (note without ANY mark-up either!!!).

So you have to realize that not only does the server side render the page it will RE-RENDER the page based on a simple button click.

And MORE important and more relevant? Well, just like ANY type of coding system such as this?

Well, then how you going to ensure that that variables, values and all that code running behind has the correct values and local variables set?

You can have arrays, lists, data grids - all server side code. All of those values, arrays and code running behind is something you do NOT have access to.

Now, when you click on a button or some such? Then the server will re-render the page, convert the controls in the aspx mark-up, THEN run the code behind, and THEN spit out the whole page and send it back down to the browser.

Note how in my above code snips:

```
Did not write loops to render the grid
Did not write loops to spit out HTML
```

So, what this means is that on your end?

You quite much have to find a way to click on the correct button on a web form. That button click will send the browser contents up to the server and all that clean non HTML and NON markup code will run. The page will be re-rendered and sent back down to the browser.

So, this means that you can't out of the blue just launch any old web page. You can no more do this then say skip a few forms in a desktop accounting package to jump to the next form.

Before that next form (say in that desktop program) loads, then all kinds of variables, arrays and even loading of data sets from a database has to occur, and ONLY THEN can the next form (on desktop) or the next web page be jumped to.

In other words, the clean non markup code behind OFTEN will set up all kinds of values, arrays, and variables in that code. And ALL OF those values have to be setup JUST right before the next page in line can be loaded/called/used etc.

You notice that as compared to old style web pages, note how most asp.net sites don't have a bunch of ugly and messy  parameters in the URL. The developer don't need them - they just setup variables and values in code (often session()) and then jump to the next web page in question.

However, in most cases it is sheer folly  to try and jump to some web page that required a previous page, and MORE important all of the previous code to run that loads up arrays, variables, and likely calls all kinds of code routines behind.

So asp.net web pages are NOT static, and they are driven by that code behind. And that code behind thus BETTER have been setup correctly and all the code run BEFORE you jump to another page.

As a result, in most cases you can NOT just type in any old URL and expect that page to work, since HOW YOU GOT to that page is MOST important.

And how you get to that page may VERY well require you to have entered values and click a few buttons on the previous page. and those button clicks and running of code behind can and will run all kinds of code BEFORE the next page loads.

If the code is missing values and setup when you shove in a URL to the browser? Then the code will bail on you. Often we write code to CHECK the previous URL, and of course OFTEN we check session values.

So, if you jump to one of my pages to display a project?

I have this code:

```
   ' before we try to load? - lets check if we have info
    If Nz(Session("ContactID"), 0) = 0 Then
        ' we don't have a contact id - jump to project page
        Response.Redirect("~/Portal/MyProjects")
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

So in above, we are loading a web page. But somehow we got to this web page without the correct contact ID being set (and note how I did not use URL parameters - I used a session() value. If that particular value is missing, then I re-direct to another page.

So, there should be ZERO surprise that pages re-render based on button clicks - that's quite much the nuts and bolts of how asp.net pages work. You click on a button - page is posted to server. Code behind runs, and then the re-rendered page is now sent back down to the client.

Of course the above model does cause a LOT of what we call round trips. But, it is a VERY fast development approach. Over time, then one will start to introduce ajax and start doing partial post backs, but the model of some kind of post-back and server side code is what makes web scraping so difficult.

Now as one introducts more client side cide (ajax calls), then often a button click will now call/make a web service call, and thus no page post-back need occur.

So, for you to web scrape here?

Well, you have to load/host the page in some type of system, and THEN BE VERY SURE YOU CLICK on the correct button(s) and VERY SURE you enter + setup the controls just right.

Since then when you jump to the next page, if all that code, variables, and values are not just right? then the code behind will choke and in most cases re-direct the web page to some error handler page, or simply re-direct back to previous page.

What makes this even more of a challenge? Well, in the above grid I exposed the PK row value of the Hotel table - but in most cases I would not and don't have to send or even ever allow the PK row value to be rendered or displayed in the client side browser side code. In other words, once again to select that one data row, you have to do the button click, since you have no means client side to set the PK row value that I going to use in the code behind when you click on that button.